# How to get the page Info.totalResults from the youtube api Search: list

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Below is the code i have created so far, my goal is to use the youtube Search: list api to find streams for specific games and then publish how many streams there are for that game, I have a database for the game titles and this is my function below, my api link does work im just not able to get the Info.totalResults from it, any help would be great, Thank you for any help you can provide

```
function totalgamelist() {
global $wpdb;
    $gamelistname = $wpdb->prefix . 'Games';
global $wpdb;
$getgames = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM '.$gamelistname , OBJECT );
    if (empty($getgames)) {
   //empty array
        echo 'This is empty sorry!';
} else {
echo 'We Got Something!'; 
        foreach ( $getgames as $getgame ) 
{
    echo '<div class="gamename">'.$getgame->GameTitle;

    $JSON = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&eventType=live&type=video&videoCategoryId=20&regionCode=US&maxResults=50&q='.$getgame->GameTitle.'&key=[API KEY]");
$json_data = json_decode($JSON, true);
echo $json_data['totalResults'];

    echo '</div>';
}
    }   
}
```

EDIT:

So with the help from johnh10, i was able to find out that it wasn't my ability to display the results although the echo johnh10 gave is correct :) it was also that my server was blocking access to the url i was asking to view. Below is the curl code i used to access the url, hope it helps others.

```
$urlgame = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&eventType=live&type=video&videoCategoryId=20&regionCode=US&maxResults=1&q='.$getgame->GameTitle.'&key=[API Key]';

    $ch = curl_init($urlgame);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$json_data = json_decode($data, true);
    if (!empty($json_data)) {
        $streamnumber = $json_data['pageInfo']['totalResults'];
echo ' Streams:'.$streamnumber;
    } else {
        echo ' Streams: No Streams Found';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $json_data['pageInfo']['totalResults'];
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to help out, I've added that string and still get nothing just shows blank